# Creating 3 war out of single pom - Maven

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have to create more than one war out of single pom:

1. With Manifest File
2. Without Manifest File
3. With Manifest but add more jars in WEB-INF/lib

to support three different application server.

Note : Its a big application and I am unable to say the reason why I am doing this.

Options tried But failed:

1. Used different execution of the war with different classifier
2. Used three Profiles and executes Using -P x,y [Where x and y are profiles]
3. When I tried with maven-assembly plugin I got issue [ Maven error: Cannot find ArtifactResolver with hint: project-cache-aware]

Is there any other way to do this.

Note I need 3 war and I don't wish to call the maven command thrice

**Update**

Right now I am running the maven build thrice from the command line [mvn -P X then mvn -P Y]. I like to do this in a single shot.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating 3 sibling projects with different maven-war-plugin configuration?
Sibling project would have dependency to your project.

Comment: But I think creating three sibling projects is not a good idea.I have to handle in the execution itself.